# s4s-elt-invalid-content.1 in XML Validation

Tags: xml, eclipse, validation, xsd

I am newbie to XML.

I am validating one XML/XSD file. But Eclipse is throwing below validation error

> s4s-elt-invalid-content.1

Here's the code where it's having issues in XSD.

```
<complexType name="Check_String">
    <complexContent >
        <extension base="tns:Boolean"/>
    </complexContent>
    <complexContent >
        <extension base="tns:String"/>
    </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

I am not sure how to solve this. Can any one explain why this error and workaround.
because of this validation of XML fails

```
 <attribute name="Reset password Call Barring"  xsi:type="tns:Check_String"  nillable="true" vdsl2Name="PSWD">
            <conditions when="BADPAYER_DisableAllForPSTN" enabled="false"/>
 </attribute>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content model of a complex type must consist of 'annotation' (if present); followed by zero or one of the following: 'simpleContent', 'complexContent', 'group', 'choice', 'sequence', or 'all'; followed by zero or more 'attribute' or 'attributeGroup'; followed by zero or one 'anyAttribute'.

Here you're showing **two** `complexContent`.

I assume that in your case, the default namespace is **http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema**

It is hard to say what you're trying to achieve; if these would be simple types, then maybe a union might help you instead, if you were trying to go after allowing both types...

UPDATE: this is an example of a union:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XML Schema Refactoring (XSR) Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:simpleType name="Boolean">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:boolean"/>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="String">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="some"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="Check_String">
        <xsd:union memberTypes="Boolean String"/>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:element name="root" type="Check_String"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: I tried the same. still validation fails. Here's my original xsd
http://snipurl.com/25argbz

Comment: XSD validation is failed as I mentioned previously. do you want .xml for the same?

Comment: Ok, you can remove the links if you don't want this public. So, you have to remove @line 1464 (may vary depending on your formatting) `<conditions when="PREACTIVATION_Enabled_CheckedandNotCREATE" enabled="false"/> 
` since it is the 5th one, where the XSD allows for a max of 4. Then again @line 1564 `<conditions when="PREACTIVATION_Enabled_CheckedandNotCREATE" enabled="false"/> 
`. Then this line `<attribute name="Reset password Call Barring" xsi:type="tns:Check_String" nillable="true" vdsl2Name="PSWD">` is really about `This is an invalid xsi:type 'CFSConfig:Check_String'`

Comment: (cont'd) there is no `Check_String` global type in your posted XSD. So you either have to create a new one which extends from `simpleAttributeType`, OR change the value to the correct one.

Comment: here's xsd http://snipurl.com/25b5gr0

Can you please upload the corrected one (xsd and xml)

Comment: Please send me an email through the support address on my website, to get in touch. We need to clarify a couple of things, then it'll be up to you to post what you like/can here on SO. Your schema and file seem real things so it'll be your decision how much you want to disclose afterwards.